# Docker: Starting the .net 8 react project in docker

Tags: reactjs, .net, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to start my .net 8 react project with docker but I'm getting this error

> error:
>
> 1>------ 1>failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to
> calculate checksum of ref
> d661c49e-d244-40cf-aed8-4da165803343::npdjyyd4vb0zsysj662l9vpi2:
> "/nginx.conf": not found1> > [react stage-1 3/3] COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

my codes below:

dockerfile:

```
# Aşama 1: Build stage
FROM node:18.17.1-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /builddir
COPY . .
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

# Aşama 2: Nginx ile React uygulamasını sun
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html/api
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 3302
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
react:
  image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}heliosecrf-react
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Helios.EDC/Helios.eCRF/ClientApp/Dockerfile
    # target: builder
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "3302:3302"
  networks:
      v3network:
          ipv4_address: 10.8.0.9
  volumes:
    - ".:/app"
    - "/app/node_modules"
```

docker-compose.override.yml:

```
react:
  ports:
    - "3302:3302"
  networks:
    v3network:
      ipv4_address: 10.8.0.9
  volumes:
    - ".:/app"
    - "/app/node_modules"
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 44458;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.htm;
    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3302$request_uri;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

I did not write the codes of the other projects in the yml file to avoid redundancy. I wrote the react part.

Comment: Based on the description it seems that this has nothing to do with .NET (and React) actually.